# Why does std::string_view::data not include a null terminator?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, string-view

This code has undefined behavior:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

void foo(std::string_view msg) {
    std::cout << msg.data() << '\n'; // undefined behavior if 'msg' is not null-
                                     // terminated

    // std::cout << msg << '\n'; is not undefined because operator<< uses
    //                           iterators to print 'msg', but that's not the point
}

int main() {
    foo("hello"sv); // not null-terminated - undefined behavior
    foo("foo");     // same, even more dangerous
}
```

The reason why is that [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) can store non-null terminated strings, and doesn't include a null terminator when calling `data`. That's really limiting, as to make the above code defined behavior, I have to construct a `std::string` out of it:

```
std::string str{ msg };
std::cout << str.data() << '\n';
```

This really makes `std::string_view` unnecessary in this case, I still have to copy the string passed to `foo`, so why not use move semantics and change `msg` to a `std::string`? This might be faster, but I didn't measure.

Either way, having to construct a `std::string` every time I want to pass a `const char*` to a function which only accepts a `const char*` is a bit unnecessary, but there has to be a reason why the Committee decided it this way.

So, why does [`std::string_view::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/data) not return a null-terminated string like `std::string::data`?

Comment: Err, but a *string-literal* is null terminated.

Comment: @WhiZTiM What do you mean?

Comment: I fail to see why you need `data` to null terminated.  If you give it a null terminated `const char*` the view will still have it.  If you don't have one then view will not add one.  That is expected behavior IMHO.

Comment: @NathanOliver If I call `foo("foo")`, the string view will not be null-terminated, even though the literal is. For practical purposes where you need a null-terminated string it would be nice to have such a function if there is no alternative.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Really?!?  If that is true then yes it is broken.

Comment: @NathanOliver See constructor (4) "Constructs a view of the null-terminated character string pointed to by s, not including the terminating null character. " http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view

Comment: @Rakete1111 Oh wow.  That is not intuitive at all.  I hope the core guidelines array_view does better.

Comment: That means simply that the size of the string_view won't include the null byte. But of course the actual string pointed to is still null-terminated.

Comment: @Rakete1111, While we shouldn't rely on `std::string_view::data()`, because we can construct a non-null terminated view using the `std::string_view(const char*, std::size_t)` constructor and the *default constructor*. I don't see any legal way to construct a non-null terminated view using the `std::string_view(const char*)` constructor (as per your example) without already invoking UB. Because that constructor supposedly calls [`std::char_traits<char>::length`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/length) to determine the length of the string which requires a null terminator.

Comment: As far as I understood `std::string_view` is supposed only take data (as parameter) not to pass it on. It is more or less just a pointer plus the length and can be used instead of `(const char* data, size_t len)`. Also it doesn't copy any data which makes it preferable over `std::string` in some cases. I think all `_view`s work like that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> So, why does std::string_view::data not return a null-terminated
>   string like std::string::data

Simply because it can't. A `string_view` can be a narrower view into a larger string (a substring of a string). That means that the string *viewed* will not necessary have the null termination at the end of a particular view. You can't write the null terminator into the underlying string for obvious reasons and you can't create a copy of the string and return `char *` without a memory leak.

If you want a null terminating string, you would have to create a `std::string` copy out of it.

Let me show a good use of `std::string_view`:

```
auto tokenize(std::string_view str, Pred is_delim) -> std::vector<std::string_view>
```

Here the resulting vector contains tokens as views into the larger string.

Answer (score 13):

The purpose of `string_view` is to be a range representing a contiguous sequence of characters. Limiting such a range to one that ends in a NUL-terminator limits the usefulness of the class.

That being said, it would still be useful to have an alternate version of `string_view` which is intended only to be created from strings that truly are NUL-terminated.

My `zstring_view` class is privately inherited from `string_view`, and it provides support for removing elements from the front and other operations that cannot make the string non-NUL-terminated. It provides the rest of the operations, but they return a `string_view`, not a `zstring_view`.

You'd be surprised how few operations you have to lose from `string_view` to make this work:

```
template<typename charT, typename traits = std::char_traits<charT>>
class basic_zstring_view : private basic_string_view<charT, traits>
{
public:
    using base_view_type = basic_string_view<charT, traits>;

    using base_view_type::traits_type;
    using base_view_type::value_type;
    using base_view_type::pointer;
    using base_view_type::const_pointer;
    using base_view_type::reference;
    using base_view_type::const_reference;

    using base_view_type::const_iterator;
    using base_view_type::iterator;
    using base_view_type::const_reverse_iterator;
    using base_view_type::reverse_iterator;

    using typename base_view_type::size_type;
    using base_view_type::difference_type;

    using base_view_type::npos;

    basic_zstring_view(const charT* str) : base_view_type(str) {}
    constexpr explicit basic_zstring_view(const charT* str, size_type len) : base_view_type(str, len) {}
    constexpr explicit basic_zstring_view(const base_view_type &view) : base_view_type(view) {}

    constexpr basic_zstring_view(const basic_zstring_view&) noexcept = default;
    basic_zstring_view& operator=(const basic_zstring_view&) noexcept = default;

    using base_view_type::begin;
    using base_view_type::end;
    using base_view_type::cbegin;
    using base_view_type::cend;
    using base_view_type::rbegin;
    using base_view_type::rend;
    using base_view_type::crbegin;
    using base_view_type::crend;

    using base_view_type::size;
    using base_view_type::length;
    using base_view_type::max_size;
    using base_view_type::empty;

    using base_view_type::operator[];
    using base_view_type::at;
    using base_view_type::front;
    using base_view_type::back;
    using base_view_type::data;

    using base_view_type::remove_prefix;

    //`using base_view_type::remove_suffix`; Intentionally not provided.

    ///Creates a `basic_string_view` that lacks the last few characters.
    constexpr basic_string_view<charT, traits> view_suffix(size_type n) const
    {
        return basic_string_view<charT, traits>(data(), size() - n);
    }

    using base_view_type::swap;

    template<class Allocator = std::allocator<charT> >
    std::basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator> to_string(const Allocator& a = Allocator()) const
    {
        return std::basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>(begin(), end(), a);
    }

    constexpr operator base_view_type() const {return base_view_type(data(), size());}

    using base_view_type::to_string;

    using base_view_type::copy;

    using base_view_type::substr;

    using base_view_type::operator==;
    using base_view_type::operator!=;
    using base_view_type::compare;
};
```

Comment: so `zstring_view` can be only a view into the tail of a string. Interesting.

Comment: Has anyone proposed such a class for inclusion in the Standard? It would be really useful for interop with C libraries, to avoid constructing full C++ string types in their interfaces if a string literal can be wrapped/viewed instead.

Comment: This looks super useful. I was just trying it out, but it doesn't work. Specifically, it doesn't compile, because `std::basic_string_view` does not provide a `to_string`, `operator==`, `operator!=` member. Surely you know this and I am just missing something obvious, but I can't see what. How does this compile for you?

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with string literals with known null terminators I usually use something like this to make sure the null is included in the counted chars.

```
template < size_t L > std::string_view string_viewz(const char (&t) [L])
{
    return std::string_view(t, L);
}
```

The aim here is not to try to fix the compatibility issue, there are too many. But if you know what you are doing at want the string_view span to have a null ( Serialization ) then it is a nice trick.

```
auto view = string_viewz("Surrogate String");
```

Comment: Make it `constexpr` and it's perfect :) Also you don't really need the function, `string_view("test")` works.

Comment: string_view("test").size() == 4; string_viewz("test").size() == 5;

Comment: This will only help with a string_view of a complete null-terminated string; it will not work properly if the view is a substring of a larger string

Comment: You are right lxop. I attempt to say that in the answer, however I can see how what I wrote could be more succinct.